# Why do we traverse backwards when using counting sort

Tags: c++

I have been using counting sort for a few days now. I have noticed that we travers backwards when using it. I was wondering why? If anyone could answer it. It would be great.

Comment: Are you asking a C or a C++ question? They are different languages.

Comment: I’m familiar with counting sort but haven’t seen anything about it iterating backwards. What code / textbook are you referencing where you see this?

Comment: @templatetypedef [link](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/counting-sort) in the c++ code they wrote `
for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    output[count[array[i]] - 1] = array[i];
    count[array[i]]--;
  }
`

Comment: Since the question is vague and does not show the code nor the source of information you want to verify, it is then a bad question. Please improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this to maintain stability because if we traverse
1 4 1 2 7 2 as the frequency of 1 is 2 if we traverse from front it will move first one to 2nd position then again again move 3 one to first position disturbing their order this doesn't affect much if we consider these two ones same but this will affect if we are using 2D array and there is some data attached to it, then this will change the order more if traverse from front ,try this by yourself on paper you will understand keeping the order point in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea behind counting sort is the following:

1. Build a frequency histogram for the original array that says how many times each element occurs.
2. Loop over the histogram, writing out the appropriate number of copies of each element.

There are many ways to translate this conceptual idea into code. The link you shared does step (2) by iterating over the histogram in reverse order, but there’s no deep reason why you need to do this. You can just as easily iterate over the histogram in the normal lowest-to-highest order and the elements will come back sorted.